Can I ask a Proof Of Work related question on crypto.SE?
I am not sure how far the concept of Proof Of Work qualifies to be on topic with crypto.SE which is why I would like to ask recommenations here first.
The question is related to me not understanding how random data can or cannot be indexed in order to shortcut some Proof Of Work scheme and henceforth defeat it.
If not directly I possible on crypto.SE I would be very happy some advice which else site of the SE universe would seen a better choice.
Thank you

Go ahead and post it!


A question about the proof-of-work algorithm itself can be asked here on crypto.
A question about proof-of-work algorithm in the context of a block chain will probably fit bitcoin.se better.
A question about how to use proof-of-work to achieve some security objective, such as making spam more expensive, fits security.se best.

Your question sounds like it falls in the first category, and thus should be fine here.
